# show div when radio button is checked is not working

Tags: jquery

I have some radio buttons. The radio button with id "showSelect" is checked by default and when the radio button with id "showSelect" is selected I want to show a div with class ".div", otherwise i want to hide the div with class ".div". I have the code below to this, but its not working, the div with class ".div" appaers by default but then if I select other radio button the div with class ".dive" is not hidden.

**//form with radio buttons**

```
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input id="showSelect"  class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" checked value="option1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
          Item 1
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1"  value="option1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
          Item 2
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**// div with class .div**

```
 <div class="form-row div">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="">
        <option selected class="selected">Item 1</option>
        <option>Item 2</option>
        <option >Item 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**//css**

```
.div{
  display:none;
}
```

**//js**

```
        if ($('#showSelect').prop('checked')) {
            $('.div').show();
        } else {
            $('.div').hide();
        }
```

Comment: And how are you triggering that show/hide? It needs to be in some sort of handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This listens for a click on any of the radio buttons, then checks the status of the desired radio button and toggles the hidden class. But your show/hide functionality must be called inside some sort of handler.

```js
// Listen for any radio buttons at the form-check
//  level being clicked.
$(".form-check input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
  // Regardless of WHICH radio was clicked, is the
  //  showSelect radio active?
   if ($("#showSelect").is(':checked')) {
     $('.div').removeClass("hidden");
   } else {
     $('.div').addClass("hidden");
   }
 })
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input id="showSelect" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" checked value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Item 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Item 2
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row div">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="">
      <option selected class="selected">Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of the ID on every Div on change state, also since your defaut checked radio button is showSelect you should let your div on display block:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input id="showSelect"  class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" checked value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Item 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1"  value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Item 2
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row div">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="">
        <option selected class="selected">Item 1</option>
        <option>Item 2</option>
        <option >Item 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
  <style>
    .div{
      display:block;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){

             $(this).on('change', function() {

              //console.log($(this).attr('id'))

             if($(this).attr('id')=='showSelect') {

                      $('.div').show();      
                  } else {

                      $('.div').hide();

                  }
            });
           })
      });
  </script>
```